# How to add the body of the subscribe method

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java2

In the below code, I am trying to add the body for the `.subscribe()`. I tried to add the lambda notation but it never worked. Would you please tell me how to implement the `.subscribe()` method?

Given that, the `setupCommRequestService()` returns Single<..>

**code**:

```
setupCommRequestService()?.
        flatMap {
            it.getAllPhotos()
                .map {
                    Observable.fromIterable(it)
                        .map {
                            it
                        }
                }
                .toSortedList()
    }
        ?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        ?.subscribe(

        )
```

Comment: do you need the result?

Comment: yes sure..but i cant add any statement or logs to print onnext and others

Comment: `Single` doesn't have  `onNext`, it only emits one value.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 implementations for `subscribe` method according [`Single`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html) documentation. In a simple approach, you should implement a strategy for both `onSucess` and `onError`. therefor you should use the `subscribe` method either by passing a `BiConsumer` or 2 `Consumer` one for `onSucess` case and one for `onError`.

using `BiConsumer` in lambda:

```
val disposable = Single.just(1)
        .subscribe { success, failure ->
            /* whichever is not null */
        }
```

or using 2 `Consumer` in lambda:

```
val disposable = Single.just(1)
        .subscribe({ success ->
            /* success */
        }, { failure ->
            /* failure */
        })
```